# File RSA Decryption

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, encryption, crt

I have a RSA Encrypted file & I want to decrypt it with C# in .NET

I have the foll. parameters of **(1024 bit enc)** message(cipher text) to decrypt

- modulus
- public exponent
- private exponent
- prime p
- prime q
- prime exponent p
- prime exponent q
- CRT coefficient

The cipher text is in HEX format

I know the CRT method to decrypt the message but not clear on how to use it

```
m1 = (ciphertext ^ dP) Mod P
m2 = (ciphertext ^ dQ) Mod Q
h = (qInv * (m1 - m2)) Mod P
m = m2 + (h * Q)
```

I tried performing the decryption using foll namespace

```
System.Security.Cryptography
```

can someone help me with a sample code to achieve decryption, as this is my first time to deal with Decryption.

Is there any ready API available? in which I just need to pass the parameters & I will receive the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may use the **System.Security.Cryptography** namespace. [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx) For some examples just dig a little deeper in to the **MSDN library**. For example, there are examples for the [RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) here.

Answer (score 0):

First create an [`RSAParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters.aspx) structure and fill it with your own RSA parameters. Next create an [`RSACryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx) instance and call [`ImportParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importparameters.aspx) on your previously defined parameters. At that point you should be able to call [`Decrypt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.decrypt.aspx) on your data with (or without) using the OAEP padding.

So something like:

```
RSAParameters p = new RSAParameters ();
p.D = d;
// ... all parameters
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider ();
rsa.ImportParameters (p);
byte[] decrypted = rsa.Decrypt (encrypted, false);
```

Comment: you mean my code should be as follows
    `RSAParameters p = new RSAParameters ();
    p.P = ""
    p.Q = ""
    p.dP = ""
    p.dQ = ""
    p.qInv = ""
    p.modulus = ""
    p.PrivateExponent = ""
    p.PublicExponent = ""

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider ();
    rsa.ImportParameters (p);
    byte[] decrypted = rsa.Decrypt (encrypted, false);
`

Comment: Yes, you should have all parameters (I don't recall if CRT parameters are required for .NET but they are not for Mono as they can be re-computed) but `byte[]` (not `string`). .NET is also picky about them being 0-left-padded to the *right* size. See other SO questions about this if this is an issue.